# Sitecore publishing in SQL Azure running slow

Tags: publishing, azure

We have a server setup of the following using 8.1 Update 2, so the CM/CDs are on Azure classic VMs:

- CM on US with SQL Azure in US
- CD on US with SQL Azure in US
- CD on EU with SQL Azure in EU

We're finding that publishing from CM to the CDs is taking an extraordinary amount of time. Doing a smart publish of the entire site, we found that going from the CM to the US CD took about 90 minutes, and from the CM to the EU CD took over 3 hours. The item count at the end was just over 88,000, so not a great amount considering a site publish.

We need to drastically reduce these deployment times. Is this a matter of giving more power via Azure configuration to the VMs or, more likely, the SQL Azure servers? There's always a cost/benefit to doing that, but I'm looking for an optimal solution and we can work back to the practical cost-wise later.

Comment: You consider the new Publishing Service?

Comment: Is that available in 8.1 Update 2? We just finished an upgrade, and if that's in 8.2 our client will likely not want to do another so soon. I've heard of it but haven't looked deeper into it, we only have one 8.2 project at the moment.

Comment: Yea. Sorry. Not available for 8.1. Get to 8.2 quick ;-)  8.1 to 8.2 shouldn't be a high effort upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the classic Sitecore publish works with one item at a time, once you add network latency to that single operation and then multiply by number of targets and languages you can see why it takes so long in some configurations.

Im sorry this doesn't help directly with you answer.

My colleague wrote a blog post on classic Sitecore publishes on Azure and this emphasises why we made the new Publishing Service the way we did and the improvements it gives by reducing latency across the board.

From UK -> West Coast US : Publish of 2hrs 53 mins reduced to 17 seconds.

http://www.ehabelgindy.com/the-awesome-performance-of-sitecore-publishing-service-v2/

Comment: It doesn't, true, but that's some fascinating data in the blog post on latency, and could help to explain why we're experiencing it. It'd be interesting if we set up an isolated test, with similar configurations and locations, and do the quick upgrade to 8.2 and try this out. The new publishing service is just out-of-box, correct - that is, it works if you use publish site/item in 8.2? Thanks!

Comment: Publishing service is an opt-in module for 8.2 so need to be installed afterwards. Quick start here: http://www.stephenpope.co.uk/publishing

If you need more info or have more questions you can come to #publishingservice on the Sitecore Community Slack.

Comment: I tried the publishing service out with an 8.2 site we had, and we went from smart publish of the whole site in 6 minutes to a republish of the whole site in 3 minutes. If we can get the trouble site upgraded, that'll be a big help. We did find the other culprit was an API hooked into the publishItemProcessed pipeline, so we're moving that as well.

Comment: Great news Ken :D